# alfresco : task opened in dashlet

Tags: javascript, url-routing, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have process that opens task automatically.

The problem is it opens it in "embedded-documentlibrary" dashlet instead of the current windows : 
[image]

I have tried to change document.URL before edit the task but same result ..

Here is my Javascript :

```
window.onload = function() {

/* appelé lors de la constitution du dashboard */
var me = this; 
var allActiveTasks = document.location.origin+"/share/page/my-tasks";
var dashboard = document.location.origin+"/share/page/site/documed/dashboard";
var lastUrlLoading = document.location.origin+"/share/page/site/documed/embedded-documentlibrary";
console.log("document.URL : " +document.URL);
console.log("lastUrlLoading : "+lastUrlLoading);
//history.pushState({}, null, dashboard);
//console.log("nouvel url : "+document.URL);

var taskIdList=[] ; 
var dashletNameList=[] ;
var nextTask = "";

// depuis le dashboard
if (document.URL == lastUrlLoading){    

    // 1er reload du dashboard :
     console.log("localStorage.getItem('oldDashlet') = "+ localStorage.getItem('oldDashlet'));
     if(localStorage.getItem('oldDashlet') != "") {                                                              

    // requête qui récupère TOUTES les tâches actives du user
    Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({

            // Note : Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI = http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/

            url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI+ "api/task-instances?authority="+Alfresco.constants.USERNAME,
            method: Alfresco.util.Ajax.GET,
            responseContentType: Alfresco.util.Ajax.JSON,
            successCallback: {
                fn: function generateForm_onSuccess(response){

                    var json = JSON.parse(response.serverResponse.responseText);

                    console.log("json.data : "+json.data);
                    // gestion de toutes les tâches actives du user, récupérées
                    if(json.data!="") {

                         // sauvegarde de chaque id et du nom de la dashlet associée
                         for(var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                                taskIdList.push(json.data[i].id);
                                dashletNameList.push(json.data[i].properties["wfvd_nomService"]);
                         }

                        // récupération de la première tâche de la Daslet en cours de traitement
                         for(var i = 0; i < dashletNameList.length; i++) {
                             if (dashletNameList[i] == localStorage.getItem('oldDashlet')) {
                                 nextTask = taskIdList[i];
                                 i = dashletNameList.length;
                             }
                         }

                         if (nextTask != ""){
                             console.log("nouvelle tâche - même dashlet " +nextTask)

                             history.pushState({}, null, dashboard);

                             console.log("nouvel url : "+document.URL);
                             window.location.href = document.location.origin+'/share/page/site/documed/task-edit?taskId=' +nextTask;

                         } else {
                             console.log("toutes les tâches de la dashlet ont été traitées");
                             //Alfresco.util.navigateTo("site/documed/dashboard");
                             localStorage.setItem('oldDashlet', '');
                         }  

                    }
                }
            }
        });
     }
}
};
```

I don't understand why it opens the task in dashlet

The first time i click on task, it opens form  in new tab. After submitting the form, the dashboard is reloded and the next task is opened automatically in "embedded-documentlibrary" dashet instead of new tab.

Comment: the above dashlet is webview dashlet right?

Comment: yes, it's a webview

Comment: You messed up the architecture of the dashlet. So its difficult to answer.Client side script should have been developed in eigther YUI script or dijit if its an aikau dashlet.I think you should make the correction, otherwise in future it may messup other things.

Answer (score 0):

@ Krutik Jayswal, this is what i have found on this webview constitution :

Share-jar src/main/resources/alfresco/templates/**{project_name}**/embedded-documentlibrary.ftl :

```
<#include "include/alfresco-template.ftl" />
<#include "include/documentlibrary.inc.ftl" />
<@templateHeader>
   <@markup id="location-hash">
   <@documentLibraryJS />
   </@>
   <@markup id="resizer">
      <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
         new Alfresco.widget.Resizer("DocumentLibrary").setOptions({
            initialWidth: 166
         });
      //]]></script>
   </@>
   <@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/modules/documentlibrary/doclib-actions.js" group="documentlibrary"></@script>
</@>

<@templateBody>
<#--   <@markup id="alf-hd">
   <div id="alf-hd">
      <@region scope="global" id="share-header" chromeless="true"/>
   </div>
   </@>-->
<div></div>
   <@markup id="bd">
   <div id="bd">
      <@region id="actions-common" scope="template"/>
      <div class="yui-t1" id="alfresco-documentlibrary">
         <div class="yui-b" id="alf-filters">
            <@region id="filter" scope="template"/>
            <@region id="tree" scope="template"/>
            <@region id="categories" scope="template" />
            <@region id="tags" scope="template"/>
         </div>
         <div id="yui-main">
            <div class="yui-b" id="alf-content">
               <@region id="documentlist_v2" scope="template"/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <@region id="html-upload" scope="template"/>
      <@region id="flash-upload" scope="template"/>
      <@region id="file-upload" scope="template"/>
      <@region id="dnd-upload" scope="template"/>
      <@region id="archive-and-download" scope="template"/>
   </div>
   <@region id="doclib-custom" scope="template"/>
   </@>
</@>
<div></div>

<#--<@templateFooter>
   <@markup id="alf-ft">
   <div id="alf-ft">
      <@region id="footer" scope="global"/>
   </div>
   </@>
</@>-->
```

Share-jar src/main/resources/alfresco/templates/{project_name}/**include**/documentlibrary.inc.ftl

```
<#--
   DocumentLibrary Template "documentLibraryJS" macro.
   Client-side JavaScript to parse initial page parameters.
-->
<#macro documentLibraryJS>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
(function()
{
   var $combine = Alfresco.util.combinePaths;

   // If no location.hash exists, convert certain params in location.search to location.hash and replace the page
   var loc = window.location;
   if (loc.hash === "" && loc.search !== "")
   {
      var qs, q, url = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.host + loc.pathname, hash = "";
      qs = Alfresco.util.getQueryStringParameters();

      var hashParams =
      {
         "path": true,
         "page": true,
         "filter": true
      },
         filterDataParam = "filterData";

      for (q in qs)
      {
         if (qs.hasOwnProperty(q) && q in hashParams)
         {
            if (q === "path")
            {
               hash += "&" + "filter=" + encodeURIComponent("path|" + qs[q]);
            }
            else
            {
               hash += "&" + encodeURIComponent(q) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(qs[q]);
               if (q === "filter")
               {
                  // Check for filterData in QueryString for the "filter" case
                  if (qs.hasOwnProperty(filterDataParam))
                  {
                     hash += escape("|" + qs[filterDataParam]);
                     delete qs[filterDataParam];
                  }
               }
            }
            delete qs[q];
         }
      }

      if (hash.length > 0)
      {
         url += Alfresco.util.toQueryString(qs) + "#" + hash.substring(1);
         window.location.replace(url);
      }
   }
})();
//]]></script>
</#macro>
```

Share-jar/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/**pages**/embedded-documentlibrary.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<page>
   <title>Document Library</title>
   <title-id>page.documentLibrary.title</title-id>
   <description>Document library with Tree view</description>
   <description-id>page.documentLibrary.description</description-id>
   <template-instance>embedded-documentlibrary</template-instance>
   <authentication>user</authentication>
</page>
```

share-jar/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/**template-instances**/embedded-documentlibrary.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<template-instance>
   <template-type>com/klinck/mc/cac/embedded-documentlibrary</template-type>
   <properties>
      <pageFamily>documentlibrary</pageFamily>
      <container>documentLibrary</container>
   </properties>
   <components>

      <!-- Title -->
      <component>
         <region-id>title</region-id>
         <url>/components/title/collaboration-title</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Navigation -->
      <component>
         <region-id>navigation</region-id>
         <url>/components/navigation/collaboration-navigation</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Actions -->
      <component>
         <region-id>actions-common</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/actions-common</url>
         <properties>
            <dependencyGroup>documentlibrary</dependencyGroup>
         </properties>
      </component>

      <!-- Toolbar -->
      <component>
         <region-id>toolbar</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/toolbar</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Documentlist -->
      <component>
         <region-id>documentlist</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/documentlist</url>
         <properties>
            <pagination>true</pagination>
            <dependencyGroup>documentlibrary</dependencyGroup>
         </properties>
      </component>

      <component>
         <region-id>documentlist_v2</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/documentlist_v2</url>
         <properties>
            <pagination>true</pagination>
            <dependencyGroup>documentlibrary</dependencyGroup>
         </properties>
      </component>

      <!-- Filter -->
      <component>
         <region-id>filter</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/filter</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Tree -->
      <component>
         <region-id>tree</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/tree</url>
         <properties></properties>
      </component>

      <!-- Categories -->
      <component>
         <region-id>categories</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/categories</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Tags -->
      <component>
         <region-id>tags</region-id>
         <url>/components/tag-filter</url>
         <properties>
            <scoped>true</scoped>
         </properties>   
      </component>

      <!-- Uploaders -->
      <component>
         <region-id>html-upload</region-id>
         <url>/components/upload/html-upload</url>
      </component>
      <component>
         <region-id>flash-upload</region-id>
         <url>/components/upload/flash-upload</url>
      </component>
      <component>
         <region-id>file-upload</region-id>
         <url>/components/upload/file-upload</url>
      </component>
      <component>
         <region-id>dnd-upload</region-id>
         <url>/components/upload/dnd-upload</url>
      </component>
      <component>
         <region-id>archive-and-download</region-id>
         <url>/components/download/archive</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Custom Code -->
      <component>
         <region-id>doclib-custom</region-id>
         <url>/components/documentlibrary/doclib-custom</url>
      </component>

   </components>
</template-instance>
```